# Invalid transform function defined on datastore in MATLAB

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation, deeplab

I am currently getting this error and I am cannot find any information to help me solve it:

Error using trainNetwork (line 184)
Invalid transform function defined on datastore.

Caused by:
Error using matlab.io.datastore.TransformedDatastore/read (line 222)
Invalid transform function defined on datastore.
Undefined function 'preprocessTrainingData' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

The code I am using is:

---

```
dataSetDir = fullfile(toolboxdir('vision'),'visiondata','fyp-preprocessed');                                          
imageDir = fullfile(dataSetDir,'trainingImages');
imds = imageDatastore(imageDir);
 
labelDir = fullfile(dataSetDir,'trainingLabels');
classNames = ["Chair","Background"];
labelIDs = [255 0];
pxds = pixelLabelDatastore(labelDir,classNames,labelIDs);

imageSize = [256 256];
numClasses = numel(classNames);
lgraph = deeplabv3plusLayers(imageSize,numClasses,'resnet18');

cds = combine(imds,pxds);   
tds = transform(cds, @(data)preprocessTrainingData(data,imageSize));

opts = trainingOptions('sgdm','MiniBatchSize',8,'MaxEpochs',3);

net = trainNetwork(tds,lgraph,opts);
```

---

Is anybody able to help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's often caused by a different shape of data being returned by the transform function to the shape of the data being read in.

Make sure the data are both the same shape.